# Timeout for ajax requests considering the browser's connection limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with ajax requests that have a fixed timeout. So I am just using this simple code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        //do something
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 7000
});
```

In my scenario it is possible that like 20 ajax requests are called at once, each with a timeout of 7 seconds. As you might know, each browser has a different number of connection limits. And here comes the problem. Some of the ajax requests are queued due to the connection limit but the timeout counting already begins. So some requests are already timed out before they even arrive at the server. Is there a possibility that the timeout is only counted down when the request is actually transmitted to the server?

Comment: "_that like 20 ajax requests are called at once_" Why?

Comment: You can write your own queuing mechanism. Compose your ajax objects and add them to the queue. Use some custom limit like 5 parallel connections, and whenever one finishes, start the next queued up one.

Comment: It's too bad jQuery no longer exposes the underlying XMLHttpRequest object - the documentation *claims* the jqXHR object is a "superset" of the XMLHttpRequest object, but it actually isn't any such thing

Comment: use native XMLHttpRequest instead - just tested with 200 requests - all succeeded :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty "replacement" for `$.ajax` - only covers what you use in the example, but it should be a "drop in" replacement

```
function betterAjax(options) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var setListener = function(which, fn) {
        if (typeof fn == 'function') {
            if (which == 'success') {
                which = 'load';
            }
            xhr.addEventListener(which, fn);
        }
    }
    xhr.open(options.method || 'GET', options.url);
    setListener('success', options.success);
    setListener('error', options.error);
    if (options.timeout) {
        xhr.timeout = options.timeout;
    }
    xhr.end();
}
```

Which is a simplified version of something I wrote some years back - basically it's https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/wpkeet34/